# Fuzzy Humanize date using Moment.js for datatable searching

Tags: javascript, datetime

In my JS project, I am using datatable plugin to show data where I have a date column which users can filter/search.

In order to help users to search using a logical string such as `today`,  `thismonth` , `lastweek` I am writting a fucntion which uses MomentJs.

I am looking at the most efficient way of writing this `fuzzyDate` function.

```js
function fuzzyDate(mydate){
  var fuzzy1 = ''; var fuzzy2 = ''; var fuzzy3 = '';

  var todaydt = moment(moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
  var daydiff = mydate.diff(todaydt,'day');
  if (daydiff==-1){fuzzy1='Yesterday'}
  if (daydiff==0){fuzzy1='Today'}
  if (daydiff==1){fuzzy1='Tomorrow'}

  var weekdiff = mydate.diff(todaydt,'week');
  if (weekdiff==-1){fuzzy2='LastWeek'}
  if (weekdiff==0){fuzzy2='ThisWeek'}
  if (weekdiff==1){fuzzy2='NextWeek'}

  var monthdiff = mydate.diff(todaydt,'month');
  if (monthdiff==-1){fuzzy3='LastMonth'}
  if (monthdiff==0){fuzzy3='ThisMonth'}
  if (monthdiff==1){fuzzy3='NextMonth'}

  return fuzzy1 + ' ' + fuzzy2 + ' ' + fuzzy3;
}

console.log( '2018-06-01 - ', fuzzyDate(moment('2018-06-01','YYYY-MM-DD')) ) ;
console.log( '2018-07-01 - ', fuzzyDate(moment('2018-07-01','YYYY-MM-DD')) ) ;
console.log( '2018-07-07 - ', fuzzyDate(moment('2018-07-07','YYYY-MM-DD')) ) ;
console.log( '2018-07-10 - ', fuzzyDate(moment('2018-07-10','YYYY-MM-DD')) ) ;
console.log( '2018-07-11 - ', fuzzyDate(moment('2018-07-11','YYYY-MM-DD')) ) ;
console.log( '2018-07-12 - ', fuzzyDate(moment('2018-07-12','YYYY-MM-DD')) ) ;
console.log( '2018-07-13 - ', fuzzyDate(moment('2018-07-13','YYYY-MM-DD')) ) ;
console.log( '2018-07-15 - ', fuzzyDate(moment('2018-07-15','YYYY-MM-DD')) ) ;
console.log( '2018-07-30 - ', fuzzyDate(moment('2018-07-30','YYYY-MM-DD')) ) ;
console.log( '2018-08-30 - ', fuzzyDate(moment('2018-08-30','YYYY-MM-DD')) ) ;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Output of the above function

```
2018-06-01 - LastMonth
2018-07-01 - LastWeek ThisMonth
2018-07-07 - ThisWeek ThisMonth
2018-07-10 - ThisWeek ThisMonth
2018-07-11 - Yesterday ThisWeek ThisMonth
2018-07-12 - Today ThisWeek ThisMonth
2018-07-13 - Tomorrow ThisWeek ThisMonth
2018-07-15 - ThisWeek ThisMonth
2018-07-30 - ThisMonth
2018-08-30 - NextMonth
```

Comment: add `fuzzyDate` to `Date.prototype`.  Makes nicely integrated, functional `Date` objects customize to your needs.  To limit scope you can:  `var fuzzy = new Date()` then add `fuzzyDate` to `fuzzy.prototye`

Comment: SO thread:  [Tomorrow, today, and yesterday in Moment.js](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35441820/463206)

Answer (score 1):

What if you have three functions that each calculate the string on its own? Therefore:

```
function days_diff(daydiff) {
  if (daydiff==0) return 'Today'
  if (daydiff==1) return 'Tomorrow'
  if (daydiff==-1) return 'Yesterday'
  return null
}
function weeks_diff(daydiff) {
  if (daydiff > 0 && daydiff < 7) return 'Thisweek'
  if (daydiff < 7) return 'Nextweek'
  return null
  ...
```

Then you can have your one aggregate function that calls the three of them...

Here's the much more complicated one from Rails that might provide guidance/inspiration: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/2c97fbf6503c9199f3fe5ed06222e7226dc6fcd9/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/date_helper.rb#L104